# Exchange Online does not set "X-Ms-Forwarded-Client-IP" header

Tags: azure-active-directory, office365, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I have managed 3rd-party IdP and configured SSO to Office 365. One day, I have turned out that 1%(only 1% but important) of WS-Trust accesses from Exchange Online do not have "X-Ms-Forwarded-Client-IP" header which is described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/operations/ad-fs-claims-types. As a result, the accesses are unfortunately rejected by the rule of IdP's IP restrictions.

Did I miss some configuration? or is it just normal?

Comment: You need to set “ X-Ms-Forwarded-Client-IP ” header. Did you checked this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/operations/access-control-policies-w2k12 .

Comment: @AlinaLi “X-Ms-Forwarded-Client-IP” header is set by Exchange Online as written in the link you attached. My question is why Exchange Online sometimes doesn't set the header.